# Using Union All performance degrades in Oracle View

Tags: oracle, select, view, union-all

I have created below oracle view where i have added select query in union all which is working fine with expected result but suddenly the performance of the view got very slow. The table `IS_ID` contains 510000 records.

I really dont understand as by adding this `UNION ALL` select query just added 400 extra rows in the view but still why the performance got very slow now. The main cause of slow performance is the below statement in `union all` which is blocking the view. Can i distribute union all or the below statement of `IS_TRE` view into different view to improve performance or how can i rewrite the below statement to improve performance ?

```
WHERE
        FUND_ISIN NOT IN
                         (
                         SELECT DISTINCT
                             FUND_ISIN
                         FROM
                             IS_ID
                         WHERE
                             MEMBER_DESCR ='O')
```

Comment: Is the query with the performance problem `select * from is_tre` or is your actual query doing anything else?

Comment: i am using this view in another view TT_RE and that view is causing the performance issue...if i remove this part from IS_TRE view then the other view TT_RE didnt get any performance issue ...the main problem is with this statment: FUND_ISIN NOT IN
                     (
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                         FUND_ISIN
                     FROM
                         IS_ID
                     WHERE
                         MEMBER_DESCR ='O')

Comment: i think the above statement is blocking the view IS_TRE somehow ..can we separate and distribute the union all in different view and also the internal select query part from union all to see if it improves the performance ?

Comment: So the query that is slow is a query that refers to another view that view relies on this one? You need to understand that Oracle takes the entire query and can rewrite it anyway that is legal in order for it to perform best. It was able to do something and come up with a fast execution plan for your requirements without this additional `union all` (which has all sorts of restrictions on query transformation - that can be worked around if you can see the query).

Comment: "Blocking the view" doesn't make any sense, what you probably meant was the additional work required to calculate the extra set rows increases the execution time. "Can we separate and distribute the union all in different view.." what do you mean? I suggest you include all the view definitions required and the full SQL statement that is slow. For bonus points include the execution plan for with and without the additional `union all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given you a few comments about why there is so much more going on that you are sharing. But here's a freebee, in general

```
SELECT 
    FUND_ISIN,    
    MAX(FUND_QUOTE_CRNY),    
    'O' AS MEMBER_DESCR,
    100 - SUM(MEMBER_RATIO),
    'Other total'
FROM
    IS_ID 
    WHERE
    FUND_ISIN NOT IN
                     (
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                         FUND_ISIN
                     FROM
                         IS_ID
                     WHERE
                         MEMBER_DESCR ='O')
GROUP BY
    FUND_ISIN;
```

Can be rewritten to

```
SELECT 
    FUND_ISIN,    
    MAX(FUND_QUOTE_CRNY),    
    'O' AS MEMBER_DESCR,
    100 - SUM(MEMBER_RATIO),
    'Other total'
FROM
    IS_ID
GROUP BY
    FUND_ISIN
HAVING sum(case when MEMBER_DESCR ='O' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

And it will probably perform better.

Whether or not that makes a difference in your actual scenario is unknown.

Comment: thanks its working and performing much better now as expected

Comment: now we know that the performance improves with sql changes...still do you see any other options also where we can try alternative for this View for performance improvement or may be sql changes ? I can then test this...

Comment: Unless you provide further information I would just be stabbing in the dark, I only use my crystal ball once per day per person. We need the full SQL you are executing and the relevant view definitions, and full execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

you can try NOT EXISTS and see if that helps

```
FROM
    IS_ID OUT_Q
    WHERE
    FUND_ISIN NOT EXISTS
                     (
                     SELECT 'X' FROM IS_ID IN_Q
                     WHERE MEMBER_IN_Q.DESCR ='O'  AND OUT_Q.COLUMNS_MAKING_UP_THE_UNIQE_KEY
                          = IN_Q.COLUMNS_MAKING_UP_THE_UNIQE_KEY
)
```